# Windows TextBox for monitoring output

Tags: c++, multithreading, user-interface, visual-studio-2012, textbox

I have a multithreaded C++ Windows application where each thread is writing output to files that I want to monitor in separate GUI elements (one per thread).  Given that I'm developing in VS2012 and can choose between CLR or MFC: What is the simplest way to provide multi-line textbox monitoring of each thread's output?

I.e., I want a GUI component to which a separate thread can write/append text, that allows scrolling back some distance, as well as the ability to select and copy text.

If it's easiest to bind the GUI component to an open file being written to by the thread please show me how to do that.

Or, if I can setup a textbox with a buffer that's safe for appending from a single non-GUI thread that's fine too.